# C# async lock get the same result without code execution

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, async-await

I have a method that returns some value based on an API call, this API limits the amount of calls that you can do per period of time. I need to access the results of this call from multiple threads. Right now i have the following code:

```
class ReturningSemaphoreLocker<TOutput>
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    public async Task<T> LockAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> worker)
    {
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            return await worker();
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
...
private static readonly ReturningSemaphoreLocker<List<int>> LockingSemaphore = new ReturningSemaphoreLocker<List<int>>();
...
public async Task<List<int>> GetStuff()
{
    return await LockingSemaphore.LockAsync(async () =>
    {
        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("SomeName");

        using (var cts = GetDefaultRequestCts())
        {
            var resp = await client.GetAsync("API TO QUERY URL", cts.Token);

            var jsonString = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>(jsonString);

            return items;
        }
    });
}
```

So the question is: how do i get the same result from `GetStuff()` if it's already running **WITHOUT** querying the API again and query the API again if the method is not running at this very moment?

Comment: Take a look at `Lazy<>`.  It can be threadsafe and all calls will block until it returns the first time and then all will be released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to hold onto the `Task<T>` that is the incomplete result; consider the following **completely untested** approach - the `_inProgress` field is the key here:

```cs
private static readonly ReturningSemaphoreLocker<List<int>> LockingSemaphore = new ReturningSemaphoreLocker<List<int>>();
...
private Task<List<int>> _inProgress;
public Task<List<int>> GetStuffAsync()
{
    if (_inProgress != null) return _inProgress;
    return _inProgress = GetStuffImplAsync();
}
private async Task<List<int>> GetStuffImplAsync()
{
    var result = await LockingSemaphore.LockAsync(async () =>
    {
        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("SomeName");

        using (var cts = GetDefaultRequestCts())
        {
            var resp = await client.GetAsync("API TO QUERY URL", cts.Token);

            var jsonString = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>(jsonString);

            return items;
        }
    });
    // this is important so that if everything turns
    // out to be synchronous, we don't nuke the _inProgress field *before*
    // it has actually been set
    await Task.Yield();

    // and now wipe the field since we know it is no longer in progress;
    // the next caller should actually try to do something interesting
    _inProgress = null;

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class that you could use for time-based throttling, instead of the `ReturningSemaphoreLocker`:

```
class ThrottledOperation
{
    private readonly object _locker = new object();
    private readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    private Task _task;

    public Task<T> GetValueAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> taskFactory, TimeSpan interval)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            if (_task != null && (_stopwatch.Elapsed < interval || !_task.IsCompleted))
            {
                return (Task<T>)_task;
            }
            _task = taskFactory();
            _stopwatch.Restart();
            return (Task<T>)_task;
        }
    }
}
```

The `GetValueAsync` method returns the same task, until the throttling interval has been elapsed and the task has been completed. At that point it creates and returns a new task, using the supplied task-factory method.

Usage example:

```
private static readonly ThrottledOperation _throttledStuff = new ThrottledOperation();

public Task<List<int>> GetStuffAsync()
{
    return _throttledStuff.GetValueAsync(async () =>
    {
        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("SomeName");
        using (var cts = GetDefaultRequestCts())
        {
            var resp = await client.GetAsync("API TO QUERY URL", cts.Token);
            var jsonString = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>(jsonString);
            return items;
        }
    }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
}
```